# search bar cancel button push to initial view controller

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, segue, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I have been searching and haven't been able to make it work.

`TableviewcontrollerA` segues a `TableviewcontrollerB` with searchbar as `firstresponder`

When user taps cancel, I want to go back to `TableviewcontrollerA`

I have tried quite a few things in the below method with no luck. What am I missing?

Thanks
BTW - The segue is done on IB, not code

```
-(void) searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{


}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
-(void) searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
    self.navigationController popToViewController:UIViewControllerA animated:YES;
}
```